# Nearby Messages API

Tags: google-nearby

I added data to eddystone beacons using Proximity Beacon. Using Nearby API,  I subscribed for `BLE_ONLY` but I am not able to receive messages from beacons `onFound()` method is not getting triggered

Comment: Check my answer to this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32453165/not-able-to-find-eddystone-beacons-using-google-nearby-api) and see if that helps!