# Nearby Messages API not getting any Attachments

Tags: android-studio, beacon, google-nearby

EDIT: Already solved, was a problem with beacons.

I'm having some troubles with Google Nearby Message API. I did as it was said on their page (https://developers.google.com/nearby/messages/android/get-beacon-messages) but it doesn't get any attachments from the beacons.

It connects to the Google API client, it successfully subscribes but it never gets to **onFound** nor **onLost**.

I tried what Andrew Bunner said in this post ([Find Eddystone Beacons using Nearby Google API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32453165/find-eddystone-beacons-using-nearby-google-api/38785160#38785160)), I got to the GITHUB repository (https://github.com/googlesamples/android-nearby/blob/master/messages/NearbyDevices/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/nearby/messages/samples/nearbydevices/MainActivity.java) and tried their App, but it doesn't work in any of my devices (Motorola Moto X 1st generation and Google Tango tablet), when I click on the switch to turn on either Discover nearby devices or Share Device information it fails to subscribe: "Could not subscribe, status = Status{statusCode=ERROR, resolution=null}".

I checked my code and compared to them and the methods are similar, but for some reason after subscribing never shows the attachments. 
I checked my API key, the manifest, the build.gradle, the beacons dashboard, the OAuth panel (and checked that indeed the attachment is there) and checked that they belong to the same project (beacons and API), but still doesn't work.
I saw some people had this same problem, but I tried to do as they were told in the answers, but seems like I'm doing something wrong and I don't see what it is.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_beacon);

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(Nearby.MESSAGES_API, new MessagesOptions.Builder()
                        .setPermissions(NearbyPermissions.BLE)
                        .build())
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .enableAutoManage(this, this)
                .build();
        Log.i(TAG, "API connected");
    }
    mMessageListener = new MessageListener() {

        @Override
        public void onFound(Message message) {
            String messageAsString = new String(message.getContent());
            Log.d(TAG, "Found message: " + messageAsString);
            //When a message is found
            Log.i(TAG, "Message found: " + message.toString());
            Log.i(TAG, "Message string: " + new String(message.getContent()));
            Log.i(TAG, "Message namespaced type: " + message.getNamespace() +
                    "/" + message.getType());
        }

        @Override
        public void onLost(Message message) {
            //When a message is no longer detectable
            String messageAsString = new String(message.getContent());
            Log.d(TAG, "Lost sight of message: " + messageAsString);
        }
    };

}
private void subscribe() {
    Log.i(TAG, "Subscribing.");
    SubscribeOptions options = new SubscribeOptions.Builder()
            .setStrategy(Strategy.BLE_ONLY)
            .setCallback(new SubscribeCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onExpired() {
                    super.onExpired();
                    Log.i(TAG, "No longer subscribing");
                }
            })
            .build();
    Nearby.Messages.subscribe(mGoogleApiClient, mMessageListener, options)
            .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(@NonNull Status status) {
                    if (status.isSuccess()){
                        Log.i(TAG, "Subscibed succesfully");
                    }else{
                        Log.i(TAG, "Could not subscribe");
                    }
                }
            });

}
private void unsuscribe(){
    Log.i(TAG, "Unsuscribing");
    Nearby.Messages.unsubscribe(mGoogleApiClient, mMessageListener);
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    Log.i(TAG, "onStart");
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {

    Log.i(TAG, "GoogleApiClient connected");
    subscribe();
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int cause) {
    Log.e(TAG, "GoogleApiClient disconnected with cause: " + cause);
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
    if (result.hasResolution()) {
        try {
            result.startResolutionForResult(this, REQUEST_RESOLVE_ERROR);
        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        Log.e(TAG, "GoogleApiClient connection failed");
    }
}

@Override
public void onStop() {

    unsuscribe();
    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }
    super.onStop();

}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_RESOLVE_ERROR) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "GoogleApiClient connection failed. Unable to resolve.");
        }
    } else {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

Comment: It sounds like two different problems, one with your app (beacons are not detected) and another with the NearbyDevices sample app (cannot subscribe).  Do you actually know that beacons are in the vicinity when testing your app?  Can you detect those beacons with either Google's [Beacon Tools](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.location.beacon.beacontools&hl=en) app or my [Locate Beacon](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.radiusnetworks.locate&hl=en) app?

Comment: Hey, I can, indeed, track the beacons on my app, in my Android console I can see the beacons, and I get a different message if they are registered, for that I use the Altbeacon Library.
I can also track and see the beacons with Google's beacon tool app.

Comment: Is Nearby turned on in Settings -> Google -> Nearby?

Comment: Just checked and it is turned on

Comment: I see you checked this for your own app, but the sample app may be giving an error at subscribe time due to a missing API key. You have to edit its manifest and add it.

Answer (score 0):

Can you turn on the following verbose logging and retry?

$ adb shell setprop log.tag.NearbyMessages VERBOSE

$ adb shell setprop log.tag.copresGcore VERBOSE

I cannot see what's wrong with your code you pasted, seems good.

Comment: I tried as you said but I got nothing as a result, well the same as always.

Comment: Can you send me the logcat info?

$ adb shell logcat -v time | tee logcat.txt

Comment: Thank's for your help, I changed the beacons (even they were working, and with other apps I could track them) and the problem was solved.